# Как исправить ссылку тега <a> в django

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, html5

в проекте django я использовал jinja в ссылках вместо стандартных url. однако jinja стал добавлять впереди url лишнее 'news'. прошу помочь исправить, т.к. в самой проблеме разобраться не смог, я пока что новичок.

код основного urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    path('me', include('main.urls')),
    path('news', include('main.urls'))
]
```

код urls.py(файл приложения, а не основной):

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name = 'about'),
    path('me', views.me, name = 'profile'),
    path('news', views.news, name = 'feed')
]
```

часть html кода шаблона:

```
    <p id="name">EVILGAMER
        <a href="{% url 'about' %}" style="margin-left: 70%;">главная</a> |
        <a href="{% url 'feed' %}"> новости</a> |
        <a href="{% url 'profile' %}"> личный кабинет</a>
    </p>
```

на скриншоте видно, как к атрибуту href добавилось 'news', хотя такую ссылку я не указывал

[image]

таким образом

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/
http://127.0.0.1:8000/me
http://127.0.0.1:8000/news
```

превратились в

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/news
http://127.0.0.1:8000/newsme
http://127.0.0.1:8000/newsnews
```

Comment: Покажите все файлы urls.py и целиком

Comment: @andreymal внес изменения в пост, оба файла urls.pu отображены полностью.

Comment: `path('news', include('main.urls'))` - вот именно здесь лишнее news и прописано

Comment: Кроме того, зачем вы один и тот же main.urls подключили трижды? В этом нет смысла, одного раза по пути `''` вполне достаточно

Answer (score 0):

Вы проделываете одну и ту же работу дважды, когда в корневом файле urls указываете включение путей с теми же путями в другом файле urls.

Исправьте ваш код на следующий:

```py
# корневой urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from main.views import index, me, news


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', index, name='about'),
    path('me/', me, name='profile'),
    path('news/', news, name='feed')
]
```

В этом случае, файл urls в приложении вам не понадобится. Можно сделать то же самое по другому:

```py
# корневой urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from main.views import index, me, news


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main.urls')),
]
```

```py
# urls.py приложения 

from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='about'),
    path('me/', views.me, name='profile'),
    path('news/', views.news, name='feed'),
]
```

Так будет более правильно. Позже, если вы будете расширять проект и создавать новые приложения, вы сможете просто подключать urls приложения в корневом диспетчере url, задавать namespace и другие параметры, сохраняя лаконичность вашего кода.

В вашем коде Django проходит по коду в корневом urls.py и, так как вы три раза подключаете один и тот же файл urls приложения, каждый раз заменяет пути на последний обнаруженный. Это как присвоить переменной значение и потом 2 раза его поменять. В последней строчке стоит путь `news` без окончания `/`, поэтому ссылки получают вид `newsme`.

Узнайте подробнее о том, как Django обрабатывает url, прочитав официальную документацию о [диспетчере url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/)